# Why overriding resetful JSONWebTokenSerializer keeps returning token only? python

Tags: python, validation, django-rest-framework, token, serialization

I found online that we are able to override JSONWebTokenSerializer by having this in our url
`url(r'^login/', ObtainJSONWebToken.as_view(serializer_class=CustomJWTSerializer)),`
and in view I have

```
class CustomJWTSerializer(JSONWebTokenSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JSONWebTokenSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['email'] = serializers.CharField()
        self.fields['password'] = PasswordField(write_only=True)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        credentials = {
            'username': attrs.get('email'),
            'password': attrs.get('password')
        }

        print(credentials)

        if all(credentials.values()):
            user = authenticate(**credentials)

            if user:
                if not user.is_active:
                    msg = _('User account is disabled.')
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

                payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)

                return {
                    'token': jwt_encode_handler(payload),
                    'user': user
                }
            else:
                msg = _('Unable to login with provided credentials.')
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "{username_field}" and "password".')
            msg = msg.format(username_field=self.username_field)
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
```

With this, I can start overriding the original but somehow the return object is always just the token.

Somehow I couldn't find where it's being generated, it does look like it's because of

```
            return {
                'token': jwt_encode_handler(payload),
                'user': user
            }
```

Even with this, user is not returned just the tokens.
I even tried taking out the whole return and have `return{}` but with the right credential, it still returns something like `{"token": null}`

I even tried using `return Response({})` but still where is it getting the `{"token": null}` from and why is it not showing my `user object` as response though? I used `print (user)` and for sure it exists that it's valid though

Comment: Please write what do you want to archive.

Comment: @Raz I want to return the user object not just the token

Comment: Overriding JSONWebTokenSerializer is not what you want. You need to use your own response payload handler. Read @hairetdin answer and accept it as a solution, cuz it is. Im not sure if his code works but the principle is correct.

Answer (score 6):

You can use additional setting - JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER - to return key and user in json response. See documentation http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/, there is an example of using JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER.

It's my code example:

settings.py

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'back.views.jwt_response_payload_handler',
}
```

in back/view.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')


def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    return {
        'token': token,
        'user': UserSerializer(user, context={'request': request}).data,
    }
```

Comment: by far the most succinct version of this that I have found. I'm saving this answer in my bookmarks :)